# What is a continuous-attractor neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, definitions

I am reading about [CANN](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Continuous_attractor_network). However, I do not seem to grasp what it is. Maybe someone who has worked with it can explain it? I found out about it while reading about RatSLAM. I understand that it helps to keep long/short term memory.